# How to use Jquery easyTicker with setInterval function properly?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery easyTicker plugin to display live scrolling news .

My requirement is that for every 5 seconds i will get the latest data from back end (ajax call) and update the livenews div

The issue i am facing is that the div data is getting disappeared after 5 seconds ??

This is my code

```
var latestnewsresponse = [
    {
        "title": "Reliance Power Q2 net up 37% at Rs 346 crore",
        "pub_date": "2015-11-03 08:48",
        "link": "http://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/reliance-power-q2-net-up-37-at-rs-346-crore-115110300604_1.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Buy Jubilant Life; target of Rs 578: P Lilladher",
        "pub_date": "2015-11-03 08:39",
        "link": "http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/recommendations/buy-jubilant-life-targetrs-578-p-lilladher_3920361.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Sensex, Nifty volatile; Amtek Auto up 17%, LT most active",
        "pub_date": "2015-11-03 08:30",
        "link": "http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/local-markets/sensex-nifty-volatile-amtek-auto17-lt-most-active_3947741.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Reliance Power Q2 net up 37% at Rs 346 crore",
        "pub_date": "2015-11-03 08:48",
        "link": "http://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/reliance-power-q2-net-up-37-at-rs-346-crore-115110300604_1.html"
    }

];

displaylivenews();

setInterval(displaylivenews, 5000); 

function displaylivenews()
{
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < latestnewsresponse.length; i++)
    {
        s += '<li><div class="itemTitle"><a href="' + latestnewsresponse[i].link + '"  target="_">' + latestnewsresponse[i].title + "</a></div>";
        s += '<div class="itemDate">' + latestnewsresponse[i].pub_date + "</div>";
        mysource = latestnewsresponse[i].link.split("://")[1].split('/')[0].replace(/(www.)|(.com)/g, '');
        s += '<div class="Source">' + mysource + "</div>";
        s += '</li>'
    }
    $("#livenewsRss").html("<ul class='feedEkList'>" + s + "</ul>").easyTicker(
    {
        direction: 'up'
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2WZQP/7/

Could you please let me now how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: You would probably need to modify the plugin or look for one that has the features you need. You aren't destroying internal interval and there is data being stored on element as well as style being adjusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I noticed was that when the `displaylivenews()` function ran for the second time, the `easyticker` plugin set the height of `#livenewsRss` to 0. So, I set the height in the plugin to the height it was setting the first time the function ran(216 pixels).

After I got it to stop disappearing on it's second execution, I noticed that it wasn't cycling. I thought this may have something to do with the first instance of the plugin never being destroyed. So, I took the advice of [underblob](http://ub4.underblob.com/remove-jquery-plugin-instance/) and added `$.removeData($("#livenewsRss").get(0));` to the beginning of the `displaylivenews()` function to kill any previous versions of the plugin instance.

Here's the new `displaylivenews()` function.

```
function displaylivenews()
{
    $.removeData($("#livenewsRss").get(0));
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < latestnewsresponse.length; i++)
    {
        s += '<li><div class="itemTitle"><a href="' + latestnewsresponse[i].link + '"  target="_">' + latestnewsresponse[i].title + "</a></div>";
        s += '<div class="itemDate">' + latestnewsresponse[i].pub_date + "</div>";
    mysource = latestnewsresponse[i].link.split("://")[1].split('/')[0].replace(/(www.)|(.com)/g, '');
        s += '<div class="Source">' + mysource + "</div>";
        s += '</li>'
    }
    $("#livenewsRss").html("<ul class='feedEkList'>" + s + "</ul>").easyTicker(
    {
        direction: 'up',
        height: '216'
    });
}
```

And here's a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fjf22q5/).